# Type inference question using Scalaz.ListW.<^>

Tags: scala, type-inference, scalaz

I was playing around with [`ListW.<^>`](http://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/ListW.scala), the definition of which is as follows:

```
def <^>[B: Zero](f: NonEmptyList[A] => B): B = value match {
  case Nil => ∅
  case h :: t => f(Scalaz.nel(h, t))
}
```

I cannot figure out how come `Option` is being chosen as the `Zero` type for this example

```
scala> case class CC(v : Int)
defined class CC

scala> val posns = List(CC(2), CC(5), CC(1))
posns: List[CC] = List(CC(2), CC(5), CC(1))
```

So now I have a List of these things. My goal is to get back an `Option[CC]` for the min/max of `posns` where I get a `None` for min if there are no values below zero and similar for max.

```
scala> import scalaz._; import Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> implicit val CCOrder = new Order[CC] { 
       | def order(v1 : CC, v2 : CC) = orderBy( (v : CC) => v.v ).order(v1, v2) 
       | }
CCOrder: java.lang.Object with scalaz.Order[CC] = $anon$1@1e48d65

scala> posns.filter(_.v < 0) <^> (_.min)
res0: Option[CC] = None

scala> posns.filter(_.v > 0) <^> (_.max)
res1: Option[CC] = Some(CC(5))
```

Option was **exactly** the `Zero` type I wanted! Can anyone explain how come `Option` is being chosen by the typer? I don't declare it *anywhere*!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definitions for `ListW#<^>` and `MA#min`:

```
sealed trait MA[M[_], A] extends PimpedType[M[A]] {
  def min(implicit r: Foldable[M], ord: Order[A]): Option[A] =
    foldl1((x: A, y: A) => if (x ≨ y) x else y)
}

sealed trait ListW[A] extends PimpedType[List[A]] {
  def <^>[B: Zero](f: NonEmptyList[A] => B): B = value match {
    case Nil => ∅
    case h :: t => f(Scalaz.nel(h, t))
  }
}
```

Here are the relevant inferred types, implicit conversion, and implicit parameters. `scalac -Xprint:typer` will reveal this.

```
object test {
  import scalaz._
  import Scalaz._

  case class CC(v: Int)
  val posns = List(CC(2), CC(5), CC(1))
  val filtered = posns.filter(((x$1: CC) => x$1.v.<(0)))
  val listw = Scalaz.ListTo[CC](posns.filter(((x$1: CC) => x$1.v.<(0))))
  listw.<^>[Option[CC]]{
    (x$2: scalaz.NonEmptyList[CC]) =>
      Scalaz.maImplicit[scalaz.NonEmptyList, CC](x$2).min(Foldable.NonEmptyListFoldable, CCOrder)
  }(Zero.OptionZero[CC]);
}
```

`List@#<^>` runs the provided function from `NonEmptyList[A] => B` if the pimped list is non-empty, otherwise returns the `Zero` for type `B`. `MA#min` actually returns `Option[B]` -- it is a general function for containers, not a specific one for `NonEmptyList`, where it could return a `B`.

A more direct way to achieve this is to call `MA#min` directly. Unfortunately, `List` already has a `min` function, new in Scala 2.8, so the implicit view to `MA` is not triggered without a type hint:

```
posns.filter(_.v < 0).min
<console>:16: error: could not find implicit value for parameter cmp: Ordering[CC]
   posns.filter(_.v < 0).min

(posns.filter(_.v < 0): MA[List, CC]).min
res7: Option[CC] = None
```

This is one of the motivating reasons to provide symbolic identifiers in Scalaz -- it is a crude form of namespacing!

Side note: you can simplify your instance of the `Order` instance for `CC`:

```
implicit val CCOrder: Order[CC] = orderBy(_.v)
CCOrder: scalaz.Order[CC] = scalaz.Orders$$anon$2@fc2528
```

Comment: At the start, you give the definition of `MA#max` instead of `MA#min`.

Comment: Ah. So my next question will be - "why is `min` coming from `MA` and not `Identity`?"

Comment: @alexey: updated. `x.min(y)` comes from `Identity`, `xs.min` matches `MA`.

Comment: Which of course I can answer immediately - "because `Identity#min` has a completely different signature!" I'm such an idiot. Thanks